# scale image of size 1600*1200

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am developing image size based iphone application. selecting two photos of size 1600*1200 from photo library and  merging of both to single image and save to same library. Again if i check the image size it shows 600* 800. How to get original size(1600*1200) of created New photo(600*800).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd help if you posted some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows.

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1600,1200)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage,self,nil,nil);
```

Thanks for all your support to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-SW8).
The `info` `NSDictionary` of the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method contains the original image.