# Resolution of image from photo library is always 640 * 480

Tags: iphone

I am working on one module where I need to pick image from photo library and draw on view.but whenever I pick the large scale images it always return me 640 *480 scaled image and because of that small image is displayed.

I have made AllowEditing ON.

can anyone help me to find the resolution of original image,so that I can again scale it to original one.

```
iImagePicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    [[iImagePicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
    iIsImageSaved = YES;
    iSavedImage = [editingInfo objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];;
    int width,height;
    width = iSavedImage.size.width;
    height = iSavedImage.size.height;

    iApp->ImagePicked(image);
}
```

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to scale your image back, it should be available anyway. Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286632/scale-image-of-size-16001200/2507817#2507817) (which is a duplicate I think..)

---

[Updated answer for your code]
You are using a [deprecated method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html), try `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` with the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key instead.

---

Added code snippet:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage* originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"Original image width: %f and height: %f", originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height);

    UIImage* editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSLog(@"Edited image width: %f and height: %f", editedImage.size.width, editedImage.size.height);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tried with that link but still I get the size 640 * 480. I have updated post with my src code.

Comment: I have updated src code with - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 //UIImage* image = nil; 
 [[iImagePicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 iIsImageSaved = YES;
 iSavedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 int width,height;
 width = iSavedImage.size.width;
 height = iSavedImage.size.height;
 
 iApp->ImagePicked(iSavedImage);
}
But still I am getting same result. I am checking it on 4th Gen iPod with 4.1 OS.